# Is has_shortcode() or get_post_meta() fatser?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add a body_class to pages, if the page has a specific shortcode.

Which of the following methods would be the most efficient one when it comes to performance?

1. Use has_shortcode() like

```
function my_body_class($classes) {
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    if( isset($post_id) && has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'my_shortocde' ) ) {
        $classes = array_merge( $classes, array( 'my-body-tag' ));
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'my_body_class', 10, 1 );
```

2. Presume that the post_meta table for the page has a custom meta_key with meta_value of true added somewhere else in the code when updating a page and you use get_post_meta() like

```
function my_body_class($classes) {
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    if( isset($post_id) && get_post_meta($post_id, '_my_shortocde_is_used') ) {
        $classes = array_merge( $classes, array( 'my_body_tag' ));
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'my_body_class', 10, 1 );
```

What would be faster? The regex that has_shortcode does or the query that get_post_meta does? Which one would you use?

**UPDATE: Wall clock timing results as suggested by @[Rimarx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5412773/rimarx)**

Option 1: Using has_shortcode()

```
Wall clock time: 8.66254170735685E-06 = 0.00000866254170735685
```

Option 2: Using get_post_meta()

```
Wall clock time: 2.88486480712892E-05 = 0.00002884864807128920
```

**Using has_shorcode wins.**

Side note: in this test the mysql db is on the same server as wordpress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check speed like that:

```
<?php
$start = microtime(true);
//Your code 
echo 'The script time: ' . (microtime(true) - $start) . ' seconds';
?>
```

As an option:

```
function my_body_class($classes) {
    $start = microtime(true);

    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    if( isset($post_id) && has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'my_shortocde' ) ) {
        $classes = array_merge( $classes, array( 'my-body-tag' ));
    }

    return 'The script time: ' . (microtime(true) - $start) . ' seconds';
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'my_body_class', 10, 1 );
```

Write the results if you try this :)

Comment: Duh, should have thought of this myself! Good suggestion! has_shortcode wins.  I'll update my question with results.